# GraalVM Native Image Error: Visual Studio 2022 Requirement Not Met

Tags: java, windows-10, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to create a native image from a simple Java program using GraalVM on my Windows 10 machine. The Java program, Hello.java, is a basic "Hello World" print statement.

I followed these steps:

1. Created Hello.java with a "Hello World" print statement.
2. Compiled it using javac Hello.java, which resulted in a Hello.class file.
3. Attempted to create a native image with the command:

`native-image Hello`

However, I encountered the following error:

```
Error: On Windows, GraalVM Native Image for JDK 21 requires Visual Studio 2022 version 17.1.0 or later (C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.31 or later).
Compiler info detected: cl.exe (microsoft, x64, 19.29.30152)
Error: To prevent native-toolchain checking provide command-line option -H:-CheckToolchain
```

[image: error]

I already have Visual Studio Community 2022 installed. What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it? Are there any specific configurations or additional steps needed to make GraalVM recognize Visual Studio 2022 correctly?

Additional information:

- System variebles/Path/ C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\
- openjdk version "21" 2023-09-19
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 21+35.1 (build 21+35-jvmci-23.1-b15)

[image: visualStudio]

Answer (score 3):

I was just in a similar boat of attempting to run a simple "Hello World" app with GraalVM(graalvm-jdk-21.0.1+12.1) and even though I already had the latest `Visual Studio 2022` installed, I was still running into the exact error you posted above.

I was eventually able to resolve the issue using this same solution in [this older answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75348946/1130979).

**TL;DR:**
A workaround to ensure the build toolchain is always added is to modify the beginning of your `native-image.cmd` file (found in in `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`) with a call to to VS 2022's vcvars64.bat, e.g.: `call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" > nul`

So the final version of my `native-image.cmd` file looked like this:

```
@echo off

call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" > nul
call :getScriptLocation location
set "GRAALVM_ARGUMENT_VECTOR_PROGRAM_NAME=%~0"
"%location%..\lib\svm\bin\native-image.exe" %*
exit /b %errorlevel%

:: If this script is in `%PATH%` and called quoted without a full path (e.g., `"js"`), `%~dp0` is expanded to `cwd`
:: rather than the path to the script.
:: This does not happen if `%~dp0` is accessed in a subroutine.
:getScriptLocation variableName
    set "%~1=%~dp0"
    exit /b 0
```

Comment: I like the idea, but for some reason when I try to implement this, I get lots of `Access is denied.` complaints (specifically on the added `call`).  Hopefully this works for others.

Comment: Nice. This works

Answer (score 2):

I saw similar errors reported by users of Chinese locale. So maybe your cl.exe reports some localized version string which `native-image` fails to parse. So one idea is to try using en_US locale.

Another thing to try is to skip VS detection, while making sure `native-image` can access the compiler:

- Start Command Prompt
- Run vsvars64.bat inside it to set up compiler paths and environment
- Run `native-image` with the `-H:-CheckToolchain` option